# Consequences of Nitrate fertilisers

Tags: reaction-mechanism, environmental-chemistry

Consider the following multiple choice.

> What is the environmental consequences of the uncontrolled use of nitrate fertilisers?

The choices are.

A. Acid rain

B. Low oxygen levels in streams

C. Ozone depletion

D. Greenhouse effect

The answer is B which is obvious why this must be an effect. However, I have read that using nitrate fertilisers also release nitrous oxide which is a greenhouse gas. So shouldn't D also be a consequence?

Comment: To me the question is poorly worded, It is not *always* the case that nitrates cause excessive algae growth, and subsequent death, removing oxygen, and yes, nitrates *in air* (e.g., wind-blown soil) *could* increase acidity of rain, and *some* nitrous oxide *does* come from fertilizer: https://news.stanford.edu/2020/10/07/laughing-gas-growing-climate-problem/ . However, the author of that question has a definite answer in mind. *sigh* If you can speak with the author, you might mention that citation. or not

Answer (score 1):

The answer should be "**All of these**".

Increased use of nitrogenous fertilizers in agriculture can significantly alter the global N-cycle because they release nitrogenous gases especially $\ce{NO_x}$. The emission of nitrous oxide ($\ce{N2O}$) contributes to the global greenhouse gas accumulation and that is causing stratospheric ozone depletion.

Nitrogenous gas can react with moisture and water vapor forming nitric acid which is a key component of acid rain. Also, as you said, these fertilizers contains nutrients which accelerate the growth of plants and crops. However, if they flow in rivers/ponds, it can lead to uncontrollable growth of algal blooms and aquatic plants leading to oxygen content in water. The process being known as "Eutrophication".

There are many papers online which has discussed on this topic but for starters, you can check below articles which has explained in simple language:

1. https://www.ndsu.edu/agriculture/extension/publications/environmental-implications-excess-fertilizer-and-manure-water-quality
2. https://www.epa.gov/sciencematters/understanding-impacts-synthetic-nitrogen-air-and-water-quality-using-integrated